# Is it possible to pass a range to a userform-property?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to adapt the code [found here](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/07/22/passing-arguments-to-a-userform/) (the third method, as that is what seems to be deemed best-practice), to suit my needs, but I'm not having any luck - the code I have so far, more or less copy-pastaed from that page is the following:

**In the form-module:**

```
Private calling_cell As Range

Property Set range_to_form(ByRef r As Range)
  Set calling_cell = r
End Property

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
  Debug.Print calling_cell.Address
End Sub
```

**In a worksheet_change-event:**

```
Dim frm As ufRegLuft

If Not IsUserFormLoaded("ufRegLuft") Then
  Set frm = New ufRegLuft
Else
  Set frm = VBA.UserForms("ufRegLuft")
End If
Set frm.range_to_form = Target
ufRegLuft.Show
```

**The problem:**

This does not work - I get an error on the `debug.print`-line, saying "Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set". I must admit I'm pretty stumped at this point, I feel like I have tried every possible combination of set, let, get etc. So, can anyone here please help me figure out if it is possible to pass a `Range`-object to an userform, and if so, tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Could you, just for debugging, not first try to see if the calling_cel range object is not nothing before doing the debug.print. It may be the case that the code is called before the range is set and works fine afterwards, after the range has been set to valid value. Maybe you can locate the source with the call stack window to see what triggers to code when the range is not set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variable `calling_cell` is initialized in the form `frm` and not in `ufRegLuft`

Change the line `ufRegLuft.Show` to `frm.Show` ;)

Here is simple way to test it.

**Form Module**

```
Private calling_cell As Range

Property Set range_to_form(ByRef r As Range)
  Set calling_cell = r
End Property

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    MsgBox calling_cell.Address
End Sub
```

**Normal Module**

```
Sub ShowFormProp()
    Dim frm As ufRegLuft

    Set frm = New ufRegLuft

    Set frm.range_to_form = Sheet1.Range("A1")

    frm.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: Darnit >.< You won't believe what a headache that "typo" has caused me :)

Comment: That is ok :) Happens with most of us ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the variable to a sub in the form, (I believe user form_Initialize will fire)

I am not sure where r is set but create a public sub in the form that sets the range, call that before you show the form then show the form like below

In the form-module:

```
Private calling_cell As Range

public sub range_to_form(ByRef r As Range)
  Set calling_cell = r
End Property

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
  Debug.Print calling_cell.Address
End Sub
```

In a worksheet_change-event:

```
Dim frm As ufRegLuft

If Not IsUserFormLoaded("ufRegLuft") Then
  Set frm = New ufRegLuft
Else
  Set frm = VBA.UserForms("ufRegLuft")
End If

frm.range_to_form r
'Could be "range_to_form r" not above
frm.Show
```

Comment: From what I understood from the article, the point of using properties instead of public variables / functions is to ensure encapsulation. While this of course would solve my problem, it doesn't answer the question of whether or not it is possible to pass a range-object to a userform-property. Thanks a lot for your input though :)